# Add reg file via Command Line on Windows CE device

Tags: registry, windows-ce

I want to create a bat file which imports an existing reg file.
I tried already the "reg" tool - I get the error "cannot execue reg.exe".
I can launch the "regeditor" via the cmd but it is no importing the reg if I append the filename to the command such as "regeditor filename". Indeed, I get no message.
If i double click on the reg file in the explorere, then the reg file is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foud the solution! Obviously, other command option letters are used in Windows CE (or on customized device which I use). I have to prefix the filname with the option "/I":
regedit.exe /I filename

Comment: It's goot to hear this got resolved, but I found no "regedit.exe" from my Win CE device, so where have u go that?

Comment: @NingYuFisher: I've been  using a 3rd party registry editor on Windows CE 5.0/6.0 for some time called "Simple Registry Editor". The Help > About says `Version v1.9` and gives a URL of `GeeksWithBlogs\BruceEitman`, but that appears to now be obsolete/defunct. This is a great viewer and does allow manual updates, but does not allow export/import of `.reg` registry files as the normal Windows registry editor allows.